# Android Activity Update

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I am calling an activity from within itself - basically i've a list of new storys and two filter buttons that when clicked restart the activity with an intent passed that changes the news stories.

When i run the app it works, but for a second i get the old activity UI while the app reads from the new xml feed and then the UI updates. Is there any way to stop this from happening and get the activity to restart cold.

here's the code I am currently attaching to the onclicklistener

```
public void openFootballNews(View v) {
 Intent i = new Intent(this, News_Landing.class); // News_landing class is the class this code is in
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("code", "football"); // this, if set, changes the xml feed to read
     i.putExtras(bundle);
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     this.onCreate(null); //this has halved the time the old UI is on the screen for but I cant get rid of it completely
     startActivity(i);
}
```

any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: hmm call finish() on the first activity when your done with it?

Comment: Reopening the `Activity` seems like a waste. It would probably be faster and less confusing to the user to update the stories in the feed instead of reopening the whole `Activity`.

Comment: thanks, i was going to update the stories but i cant seem to get getView in my custom adapter to run a second time.

Comment: calling finish doesnt seem to affect it, the problem seems to be the saved state, when the activity loads it uses the last state it was in before closing until the new view is set - this is the problem - i need to find a way to clear that saved state!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting an activity from itself doesn't make much sense (unless your aim is to do something esoterically recursive ;) ). Also, I may be mistaken, but I believe activities are kept in a stack so that as you flip between news stories, you're piling up one nearly-identical activity after another. I'd similarly think calling `onCreate()` by hand is bad form.

Would need to see all of your code, but my guess is that you are reading your feed and creating your list inside `onCreate()`, and that your best bet is to refactor that into a `openNews(String sport)` method, which you call once in `onCreate()` and again in your listener(s).